# Problems with translations with Vue, Yup and i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yup, vite, vue-i18n

I have a Vue.js App (with Vite) where I use Vee-validate with Yup for form validation and use i18n for message translation. However, the custom errors in the schema do not update in real time when the user sets `$i18n.locale='xx'`

Schema:

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n"

const {t} = useI18n()

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup
    .string()
    .required(t("field_required"))
    .email(t("field_error_email")),
  password: yup.string().required(t("field_required"))
})
```

Messages printed directly to the template with `$t("message")` work normally.

Versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vee-validate": "^4.5.11",
    "vue": "^3.2.33",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t("field_required")` is passed as a string during component setup, it cannot be reactive. In order to be reactive, it should be evaluated at the time when a message really needs to be accessed, i.e. during schema validation. It's expected that `required`, etc schema methods accept a function to evaluate a message lazily for this purpose, and they actually do.

It should be:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup
    .string()
    .required(() => t("field_required"))
    ...
```

Comment: This only works if the validation is called again, i.e. the form is submitted or the field value is changed. Would there be a way to update as soon as the language is changed? I generate the error > change the language > the error is updated according to the new language?

Comment: I can't say because the question doesn't contain the code you describe. The validation likely needs to be done inside language watcher.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a watcher, it would look something like this:

```
   watch(i18n.global.locale, () => {
     if (<TOBEVALIDATED>.meta.value.touched) <TOBEVALIDATED>.validate();
   });
```

*meta* and *validate* are both values that can be desctructured from useForm() if you use e.g. vee-validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your translated string like that :

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    email: yup.string('Must be string')
                .email('Must be email')
                .required('Required input'),
    password: yup.string().required().min(6),
});
```

[image]

also check this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#validation-tests

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way but I get a message with "".
For example, we should get (The Password field is required) but we get ("The Password field is required").

Here is my code.

```
import UseForm from '@/composable/validation/schemas/UseForm';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const mRequired = (fieldName: string) => {
  const { t } = useI18n();
  return computed<string>(() => {
    return t('validation.required', { field: t(`fields.${fieldName}`) });
  });
};

const { errors, values, handleSubmit, resetForm } = UseForm(
  yup.object({
    password: yup.string().required(mRequired('password')),
  }),
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etDvB.png)